# How to connect date inputs to image outputs in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, input, output

I am trying to write a code where, upon selecting a certain date, a specific image with a caption will be produced. I mainly only know HTML and I believe this requires more javascript knowledge so I am having a hard time. This is what I have so far, it could be totally wrong. I am pretty new at this, I apologize for the basic code and thank you so much for the help

I've tried putting in different other lines but nothing seems to work or just add more of a mess

```
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="value1"
   value="2019-04-01"
   min="2019-04-01" max="2019-11-07">

<output name="images/1.JPG" for="value1" form="foo"</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you have a set of list images, and you already prepare for the image and label. Then using jascript, you add listener to the dropdown. When the value change you run a function that will set the image url and the caption. Please kindly find the code below

```js
const date = document.getElementById('myDate');
const images = {
  "2019-04-01": {
    "url": "https://www.randomlists.com/img/things/television.webp",
    "label": "main-image"
  },
  "2019-04-02": {
    "url": "https://www.randomlists.com/img/things/credit_card.webp",
    "label": "second-date"
  }
};

date.addEventListener('change', () => {
  const image = document.getElementById('image');
  const caption = document.querySelector('.caption');

  image.setAttribute('src', images[date.value].url);
  caption.innerHTML = images[date.value].label;
});
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDate" name="value1" value="2019-04-01" min="2019-04-01" max="2019-11-07" />

<img src="" id="image" />
<label class="caption"></label>
```